# Delphi - Duplicate tpanel and tbuttons on second form

Tags: delphi, tpanel

On my main form I have a TPanel containing buttons that act as a toolbar.  I want to clone/copy this toolbar and the buttons and their functionality to a second form.

Cloning the menu was simple using newmenu.merge(mainmenu).  That was an excellent shortcut to duplicating a Tmainmenu.

But I am at a loss on how to easily duplicate my toolbar without having to manually assign the events and keep a timer to compare and track which buttons are enabled and disabled in comparison to the real mainmenu on the main form.  Depending on what the application is doing the main toolbar buttons will be enabled and disabled at various times.

Any ideas here?  Thanks for any suggestions or tips to make this easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Duplicating the controls**

  In the Form Designer, select the panel and press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to copy it and all its children to the clipboard. Go to the second form and press <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> to paste.

  If you're still working on the design and want to keep it consistent between both forms, then create a [`TFrame`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TFrame) and design your toolbar layout there. Then put an instance of that frame on both your forms. Changes to the frame design will be reflected in the forms.

  See [*Working with frames*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Working_with_Frames) in the help.
- **Making sure both sets of buttons are enabled consistently**

  Create a data module. Put a [`TActionList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ActnList.TActionList) on it. Add an action to it for each button on your main form. Assign event handlers to the actions' `OnUpdate` events. In them, set the *actions'* `Enabled` properties. Finally, assign each button's `Action` property to refer to the corresponding action object. The buttons will *automatically* get enabled and disabled with the actions. No timer required.

  Furthermore, you can handle the actions' `OnExecute` events, too. Clear each button's `OnClick` property, and then move the button's `OnClick` code into the corresponding action's `OnExecute` handler. It will automatically get called when you click the button, even though the `OnClick` property is empty.

  When you assign the `Caption` or `Hint` property of a `TAction`, the corresponding properties of any associated controls also change. Likewise for images, if the control supports them. Actions can be assigned to menu items, too.

  See [*Using action lists*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Action_Lists) in the help.
- **Acting like a toolbar**

  Just use [`TToolbar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TToolBar). That's what it's for.

  Or, once you're used to actions, put a [`TActionManager`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ActnMan.TActionManager) in your project and use it with [`TActionToolbar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ActnCtrls.TActionToolBar) and [`TActionMainMenuBar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ActnMenus.TActionMainMenuBar). See [*Organizing actions for toolbars and menus*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Organizing_Actions_for_Toolbars_and_Menus) in the help.

Comment: Thanks, the frame option worked fine.  I hadn't used them before and my existing method was a standard tpnael with buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Are the buttons attached to actions?  If so, you can use the OnUpdate event of the TActionList to specify what should and should not be enabled.  If not, it isn't too much work to convert to using actions.

If you go this route to convert to using a ActionList, consider putting the ActionList in a datamodule where different units and forms could reference it.

Answer (score 0):

> > You can Use ClipBoard Object For Copy Your Panel.

Clipboard.SetComponent(Panel1);
Clipboard.GetComponent(Form2,GroupBox1);